# How can I spawn huge number simultaneous HTTP HEAD requests in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, webrequest

We have a server that does image manipulation based on a query string and then renders the result. The result is also cached for 90 days. Because of the complexities, some manipulations can take 6-7 seconds.

A marketplace where we list some of our products has recently reduced their timeout when fetching images to a low value causing most of the items in any given feed to fail the first time due to (their error message) "Image Timeout". When we resubmit the feed there are no such problems since our image server now has the images cached.

Please *do not* suggest asking the marketplace to change their timeout.  They are ridiculously inflexible and uncooperative. Also, please do not suggest getting a more powerful image server. It is actually a massive farm and is not in my team's control.

That leaves me with one option. I need to "prime the cache" before sending the feed to the marketplace. The problem is that a feed can contain up to 5000 items which have at least 2 images each. That means 10,000 images.

I am using a `HEAD` call since we don't need the image returned to us. I have tried using `WebRequest` and even `Socket` in the .Net Framework, called inside an async `Task` (using Task.Run()`) but the CLR will only spin up somewhere around 20 tasks at a time. Since, on average, each image takes about 4 seconds (some up to 6-7 seconds, some only 1 second), you take 10,000 / 20 = 500 * 4 seconds = 2000 seconds = 33 1/3 minutes, which is not an acceptable wait on our end before we send the feed.

Since we don't actually need the reply from our image server, I tried to use an async request to the image server and that gets through the `foreach` in record time but, as I found out, using that async request I am not guaranteed that the call is even triggered by the time the code that spins up all the tasks finishes so that doesn't help.

We use AWS so I have considered using Lambdas, but that would add extra complexity and expense, but the massive parallel ability there sounds like it would do the trick.

How can I fix this?

Test Server

```cs
public class HomeController : Controller {
    private Random random;
    public HomeController() {
        random = new Random(DateTime.UtcNow.Millisecond);
    }
    public ActionResult Index(string url) {
        var wait = random.Next(1, 70);
        Thread.Sleep(wait * 100);
        return Content(wait + " : " + url);
    }
}
```

Test Client

```cs
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
            Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
            var task = SendRequest("http://test.local.com/Home/Index?url=" + i);
            tasks.Add(task);
        }
        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
    }
    private static async Task SendRequest(string url) {
        try {
            var myWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);
            myWebRequest.Method = "HEAD";
            var foo = await myWebRequest.GetResponseAsync();
            //var foo = myWebRequest.GetResponseAsync();
            //var foo = myWebRequest.GetResponse();
            foo.Dispose();
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

Comment: Connection pool limits perhaps? (For WebRequest, but not Socket.) The CLR is definitely happy to spin up more tasks than that.

Comment: Wow! Jon Skeet.  Well, if anyone can help me I know you can.  I ran ``ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads`` and got back 32K and 1000 so there appear to be plenty of workers and IO connections available.  How do I get the CLR to use them?

Comment: Without knowing what your current code looks like, it's hard to say what to change. Please provide a [mcve]. (Ideally with a tiny web server as well, just using HttpListener - that can simulate the delay, and count the concurrent requests.)

Comment: Try `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, 100);` to see if that makes any difference.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, thanks for the suggestion.  I did a face-palm when I read it.  Unfortunately I just tried it at 100, 100 and even 1000, 1000, neither one helped.  I was SO hoping that would do it.

Comment: Do you know the order in which the marketplace requests your images? Is it the same order they appear in the feed? It seems that what you have to do is to request the images from your image server in the same order, and a little faster than them!

Comment: @TheodorZoulias There is no guarantee in the order.  Plus, the item feed is sent as one payload (we are only allowed 6 feeds per hour) so we can't send the feed and then attempt to prime the cache.  I like your thinking, though!

Comment: @JonSkeet, sample code has been added

Comment: So the problem is that you can't request the images fast enough? How about removing the awaiting from `var foo = await myWebRequest.GetResponseAsync();`. You don't want to wait. Maybe firing-and-forgeting the tasks will make things run faster!

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, see initial text. I already tried that. Note the commented out line of code right below the `await`. If you don't `await` an async method you are not guaranteed that the code inside it fired because the CLR simply adds it as a `Task` to the list of things to do, so when your process terminates that Task may not have fired yet. Run the sample code and remove the `await` then look at the web server logs. You will see that only the first few (if any) calls actually got logged by your server.

Comment: @AndrewSteitz When I run your test code, concurrency is generally limited to my CPU core count. If I switch the test server's `Index()` to be async (return `Task<ActionResult>` and use `await Task.Delay(…)`) then this limitation goes away and I can run hundreds of requests in parallel through the test client. If you haven't done so already, I recommend running concurrency load testing against your web server to verify that it isn't actually a bottleneck. Using JMeter, I'm able to run ~3,000 requests concurrently against my modified test server.

Comment: I had exactly the same experience as Fls'Zen. (Admittedly I changed the client to use `HttpClient` as well, but it was making the server use async that really made a difference.)

Comment: Much obliged gents. I had not even considered that my client code (which has seen several changes) would be OK now and that my test server (running on my dev machine) would be the bottle neck. I will run a test against our actually image server, which is a massive farm and should be able to handle the load.

Comment: No dice. However, perhaps our load balancer is not distributing the requests because they are all coming from one machine in rapid succession and the lb is trying to prevent one client from flooding the entire farm.

Comment: In the long run it could be more efficient for the image server to obtain the functionality of accepting a list of URLs and caching them. It could do it with minimal overhead as a low priority job, and hopefully fast enough for the needs of your team. Bombarding the server with a ton of concurrent requests may have the same effect as a DOS attack. 

Comment: @TheodorZoulias we have discussed this very idea but that is outside the scope of my team. Not saying it isn't a possibility, just not a priority for the other team. Also, the image server is not "A" server, it is a massive farm so there would need to be more work down to split up the work amongst the various actually servers. To your last point, I specifically asked the team in charge of the image service about what kind of work load I can send without DOSsing them. They said our their service can handle our needs. :)

Comment: In my comment above, by "very idea"  I meant the notion of the image server/service accepting a list of URLs to process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate answering my own question but I want to share what I ended up doing in case anyone else runs into the same problem. Basically, I encapsulated the code that calls the image service into it's own tiny executable and then I use `Process.Start()` to run the executable. I definitely expected to see an increase in performance but I was surprised by just how much of a boost I saw. The boost was approximately a factor of 20 and the CPU usage on the machine only went up to 20-40% depending on how many concurrent batches I ran and how big the batches were.

In the code below, please keep in mind that I have removed `try{}...catch{}` blocks to keep the code compact.

Separate executable (name of project is `ImageCachePrimer`)

```cs
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var tasks = new List<Task>(args.Length);
        foreach (var url in args) {
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () => await SendRequest(url)));
        }
        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
    }
    private static async Task SendRequest(string url) {
        var myWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);
        myWebRequest.Method = "HEAD";
        var foo = await myWebRequest.GetResponseAsync();
        foo.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Method to call the executable.

```
private static Process CreateProcess(IEnumerable<string> urls)
{
    var args = urls.Aggregate("", (current, url) => current + url + " ");
    var start = new ProcessStartInfo();
    start.Arguments = args;
    start.FileName = "ImageCachePrimer.exe";
    start.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    start.CreateNoWindow = false;
    start.UseShellExecute = true;
    return Process.Start(start);
}
```

Method which calls the above method

```
private static void PrimeImageCache(IReadOnlyCollection<string> urls) {
    var distinctUrls = urls.Distinct().ToList();
    const int concurrentBatches = 20;
    const int batchSize = 15;
    var processes = new List<Process>(concurrentBatches);
    foreach (var batch in distinctUrls.FormIntoBatches(batchSize)) {
        processes.Add(CreateProcess(batch));
        while (processes.Count >= concurrentBatches) {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            for (var i = 0; i < processes.Count; i++) {
                var process = processes[i];
                if (process.HasExited) {
                    processes.Remove(process);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    while (processes.Count > 0) {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        for (var i = 0; i < processes.Count; i++) {
            var process = processes[i];
            if (process.HasExited) {
                processes.Remove(process);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The separate executable and method that calls it are pretty straightforward. I would like to explain some nuances in the final method. First, I initially tried using `foreach(var process in processes){process.WaitForExit();}` but that made it so that every process in the batch had to finish before I could launch a new one. It also caused the CPU to spike to 100% (I guess internally it does a near-empty loop to see if the process is finished). So, I "rolled my own" as seen in the first `while` loop.
Second, I had to add the final `while` loop to make sure that the processes that were still running after I queued up the final batch in the previous `foreach()` had a chance to finish.

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: This seems pretty solid, although going for a multi-process solution always seems like a concession to me (because of the added complexity). In an ideal world the same should be doable (and equally performant) using a single process.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Agreed.  I was loathe to go this route but in the end I could not find a way to make a single process spawn enough threads.  I would love to see anyone else's solution to this that does not involve spawning external processes.